# code sandbox iframe doesnt work in Github Pages Page

Tags: iframe, markdown, github-pages

it must be something stupid but im scratching my head for about 2 hours from now...

see https://eliav2.github.io/how-react-hooks-work/#basic and go few lines down
the raw file is [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Eliav2/how-react-hooks-work/master/README.md)

you will see

```
<iframe 
  src="https://codesandbox.io/embed/github/Eliav2/how-react-hooks-work/tree/master/?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&initialpath=basic&module=%2Fsrc%2FexampleFiles%2FBasic.jsx&theme=dark"
  style="width:100%; height:500px; border:0; border-radius: 4px; overflow:hidden;"
  title="example"allow="accelerometer; ambient-light-sensor; camera; encrypted-media; geolocation; gyroscope; hid; microphone; midi; payment; usb; vr; xr-spatial-tracking"
  sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-presentation allow-same-origin allow-scripts"></iframe>
```

as text and not as embedded iframe. i don't have anything logged on the console and can't figure out why this is not working.
tried also wrapping this with div, but it seems that the markdown processor of Github Pages treats the  as text. why?

how can I embbed code sandbox in github pages correctly?

### update:

I'm using [GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://github.github.com/gfm) which states about iframe [the following](https://github.github.com/gfm/#disallowed-raw-html-extension-).

how can I handle it.

Answer (score 0):

In `_config.yml` file, remove the `tagfilter` extension from the `commonmark > extensions` field. Maybe you would need adding `UNSAFE` to the `commonmark > options` field too:

```yaml
markdown: CommonMarkGhPages
commonmark:
  options: ["UNSAFE", "SMART", "FOOTNOTES"]
  extensions: ["strikethrough", "autolink", "table"]  # Remove `tagfilter` from here
```